# How to Create a Square Link with Text Vertically-Aligned in Center and Word-Wrapping?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, vertical-alignment

I thought this would be very straightforward with a simple `display:inline-block`  and `vertical-align:middle`, but nothing I try works.

Is it possible to create a square that is 100px by 100px with text horizontally and vertically centered and wrapped and where the entire square is a link?

If the text is wider than the square, then the text must wrap below and the entire text must still be vertically and horizontally-centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can make text center using `display:flex`.

```css
.main {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
Some text in center
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to do it without {display:flex} that is compatible with more devices and browsers?

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl. Yeah it is compatible for all latest browser. Your can check it here. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/